# passing json values in sql select statement

Tags: json, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to pass the each line of json file to the SQL Select statement.How I can pass the values using python in iterative way

Json File contains following lines :

```
{"row_id":"1","a":"600","b":"hello","date":"2017-07-01","enabled":"TRUE","id":"234"}
{"row_id":"2","a":"650","b":"world","date":"2018-08-02","enabled":"FALSE","id":"456"}
{"row_id":"3","a":"700","b":"world","date":"2019-02-10","enabled":"FALSE","id":"789"}
```

I am trying to pass each line values to the sql statement.
Eg :

when row_id = 1 then it should pass the values of the respective line

```
Select * from xyz where a='600' and b='hello' and date ='2017-07-01';
```

when row_id =2 then then it should pass the values of the respective line

```
Select * from xyz where a='650' and b='world' and date ='2018-08-02';
```

when row_id =2 then then it should pass the values of the respective line

```
Select * from xyz where a='700' and b='world' and date ='2019-02-10';
```

Thank you

Comment: Couple of questions... What version of SQL Server?  Is xyz an actual table or view and you are using the JSON as selection criteria?

Comment: SQL Server version : 13.x  ,xyz is the actual table, I am using json as selection criteria.

Comment: OK, when you say 13, I'm assuming SQL Server 2016 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are passing one JSON object at a time

**Example**

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max) ='{"row_id":"1","a":"600","b":"hello","date":"2017-07-01","enabled":"TRUE","id":"234"}'

SELECT * 
 From  xyz 
  Where  a = JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.a') 
    and  b = JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.b') 
    and  date = JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.date')
```